# Flink- error on running WordCount example on remote cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-flink

I have a Flink Cluster on VirtualBox incliding three node, 1 master and 2 slaves. I customized WordCount example and create a fat jar file to run it using VirtualBox Flink remote cluster, But I faced Error.

**Notice**: I imported dependencies manually to the project(using Intellij IDEA) and I didn't use maven as dependency provider. I test my code on local machine and it was OK!

More details are following:

Here is my Java code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class WordCount {

// *************************************************************************
//     PROGRAM
// *************************************************************************

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    final int port;
    final String ip;
    DataSet<String> text;
    try {
        ip = params.get("ip");
        port = params.getInt("port");
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(ip, port, 2);
        text = env.readTextFile(params.get("input"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("No port or input or ip specified. Please run 'SocketWindowWordCount --ip <ip> --port <port>'" +
                " --input <input>");
        return;
    }

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
            text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
                    // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
                    .groupBy(0)
                    .sum(1);

    System.out.println("Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.");
    counts.print();

}

// *************************************************************************
//     USER FUNCTIONS
// *************************************************************************

/**
 * Implements the string tokenizer that splits sentences into words as a user-defined
 * FlatMapFunction. The function takes a line (String) and splits it into
 * multiple pairs in the form of "(word,1)" ({@code Tuple2<String, Integer>}).
 */
public static final class Tokenizer implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    @Override
    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
        // normalize and split the line
        String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");

        // emit the pairs
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.length() > 0) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(token, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

I created ExecutionEnvironment object using command:

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(ip, port, 2);
```

, And I run the code using the following command on host machine(that is connected to the cluster nodes and VirtualBox is running on that)

```
java -cp FlinkWordCountClusetr.jar WordCount --ip 192.168.101.10 --port 6123 --input /usr/local/flink/LICENSE
```

, But I faced the following error(in summarized):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not start the ActorSystem needed to talk to the JobManager.
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.log-received-messages'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: can you access the remote environment from where you are running the job?

Comment: @BiplobBiswas of course, I can ping address `192.168.101.10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many settings, it was all about maven dependencies was not matching Flink version installed on the remote cluster. Maven dependencies were Flink version `1.3.2` build on Scala `2.10`, while Flink installed on the remote cluster was `1.3.2` build on Scala `2.11`. Just a minor difference but important!